# How do I navigate to a new page with a Button in ASP.net Core?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net-core

I've got a webpage that currently links to another page like this:

```
<a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
```

I've tried this and it just sat on the page very happily, but didn't take me where I want to go:

```
<button asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
```

**How can I change this to use a button instead of a text link?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```
<a asp-action="Create"><button class="btn btn-primary">Create</button></a>
```

Comment: Editor warns me that Element 'button' cannot be nested inside element 'a'.

Comment: You need to add the type="button" for this to work properly `<button type="button"`

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned you want to navigate to a new page I'd use a different controller for it that has the Create action (or just an Index action).  You can nest an input inside an anchor tag.

```
<a asp-controller="DifferentControllerName" asp-action="Create">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create"/>
</a>
```

It renders like this:

```
<a href="/DifferentControllerName/Create">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `Javascript`;

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href='@Html.Action("Create")'">Create</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Or Edit 
and 

 $(document).ready(function () {

```
        $("#Some").click(function (e) {
            var _url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
        window.location.href = _url;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the `<button>` tag simply use the `<input>` tag as demonstrated below.

It's important to note that the `<input>` tag cannot have a closing tag and therefore the `value` attribute is used.

```
 <a asp-action="Create"><input class="btn btn-primary" value="Create"/></a>
```

I presume this is the way you wanted to do it.

Comment: This doesn't cause the cursor to behave as a link...in contrast to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55167786/155892

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation on Oluwafemi's answer which works for me. Only issue with this is that you cant use `button.disabled = true;` in javascript to disable the button, so I hide it instead.

```
<a button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="Btn" asp-area="" asp-controller="Name" asp-action="Action">Button Text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the controller has the Create method calling the view

```
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

If not create a view there